# Task scheduling algorithm that limits concurrency

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, concurrency, multi-tasking

My prof introduced us an algorithm with semaphores that was used to solve the "dining philosophers" problem.
The algo is ok, apart from that it limits concurrency.

What does mean that it "**limits concurrency**" and why this happens ?

[image]

Comment: It means that it can miss some opportunities for more philosophers being able to progress. For instance, if phil1 grabs fork5 and waits for fork1, this can unnecessarily prevent phil5 from eating.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, That sounds like a good answer to me!  Can I encourage you to write that in the answer box rather than in the comment box, so we can upvote it?  Stack Exchange discourages writing answers in the comments.  No need to expand on your answer, that seems sufficient to me in its current form.